# Cloudfront CDN performance, not matching existing CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have put my Rest API behind CloudFront CDN, and was just testing performance. Of

- My Service Without CDN
- My Service With CDN
- Other Service with CDN

[image]

All tests were carried out from my PC with Jmeter, in the same conditions. Also, I can confirm then the configuration for the CDNs are the same.

I can see a performance increase on My Service (Average - 234 vs 134). But when comparing with the Other Service on CDN (Average - 134 vs 88) , it does not match up.

Why is Cloudfront performance, different for different CDNs? How can I optimize it?

Comment: What does "Other Service" do? Does the service do less work? Is it e.g. running in Lambda@Edge?

Comment: @luk2302 It actually calls my service and a bunch of others. To aggregate data.